# Event type expression never true on focus / blur

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got the following piece of code that's supposed to slideUp a div on focus of an input, and slideDown on blur. But the only thing that's happening is slideUp.

So I'm guessing that `e.type === "focus"` never evaluates to true for some reason.

Does anybody know what's the issue?

```
// When input is focused / blurred,
// toggle slide on input message except error.
$form.on("focus blur", "input", function (e) {
    var $div = $(this).siblings("div");

    if (!$div.has(".error").length) {
        e.type === "focus" ? $div.stop().slideDown("fast") : $div.stop().slideUp("fast");
    }
});
```

Comment: Show some HTML that goes with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When alerting e.type, the events are called "focusin" and "focusout" accordingly (in Chrome), so try changing your code to:

```
e.type === "focusin"
```

Comment: In Chrome only? That means it wouldnt work on other browsers?

Comment: I just stated that it is "focusin" in Chrome - I don't know if type is browser dependent or abstracted by jQuery. If the former is the case, the easiest solution might be using two event handlers (one for focus and one for blur).